# What happens when I create an index on a column?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I asked multiple question about indexes already. Something like this:

Would following queries benefit from this index? `mytable(col1, col2, col3)`

```
. . . WHERE col1 = ? AND col3 = ?
. . . WHERE col2 = ?
. . . WHERE col1 IN (?, ?)
. . . WHERE col3 = ? AND col1 NOT IN (?, ?)
. . . WHERE col1 = ? OR col2 = ?
. . . WHERE col2 = ? AND col1 = ?
. . . WHERE col1 = ? AND col2 > ?
. . . WHERE col1 = ? AND col3 > ?

-- each question was containing one of these queries ;-)
```

Every time I got an answer for that specific query which was mentioned in that question, and still I cannot judge such a index would be useful for such a query or not. *(or how making it more optimal)*

So I decided to ask this question and want to know about the backstage. What happens when I create an index on a column? An index is made of what? An multiple column index is containing what rows *(because order is important)*? How it works which causes a query much faster?

Actually I need some information about indexes to make me able how can I determine a proper index *(multiple columns or single column)* for a query.

**Note:** I have some experiences to work with `EXPLAIN`. And yes I know using `EXPLAIN` is really useful in these cases. Now I just need some further information.

Answer (score 2):

An index puts the value, or part of the value in RAM so its faster to access. An index with more than one column aggregates the contents.

So an index with `(col1, col2, col3)` will be useful for all queries that contain `col1` lookups, because `col1` is the left-most.

It will be even more beneficial for lookups of `col1` and `col2`, because after getting all the matches for `col1`, then it can use the `col2` part too.

Finally, the `col3` part will only ever be used if `col1` and `col2` have been used already, so its unlikely that it will be useful. But it may be.

Answer (score 1):

This eval are based only on the where clause you show ... can change depending of the select column

```
    . . . WHERE col1 = ? AND col3 = ?               yes partial (only col1)
    . . . WHERE col2 = ?                            no
    . . . WHERE col1 IN (?, ?)                      yes 
    . . . WHERE col3 = ? AND col1 NOT IN (?, ?)     yes partial (only col1)
    . . . WHERE col1 = ? OR col2 = ?                yes
    . . . WHERE col2 = ? AND col1 = ?               yes
    . . . WHERE col1 = ? AND col2 > ?               yes 
    . . . WHERE col1 = ? AND col3 > ?               yes partial (only col1)
```

for a good explanation of how index work on mysql you can see this ref http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html

from the doc

> MySQL uses indexes for these operations:
>
> To find the rows matching a WHERE clause quickly.
>
> To eliminate rows from consideration. If there is a choice between
>   multiple indexes, MySQL normally uses the index that finds the
>   smallest number of rows (the most selective index).  If the table has
>   a multiple-column index, any leftmost prefix of the index can be used
>   by the optimizer to look up rows. For example, if you have a
>   three-column index on (col1, col2, col3), you have indexed search
>   capabilities on (col1), (col1, col2), and (col1, col2, col3). For more
>   information, see Section 9.3.5, “Multiple-Column Indexes”.
>
> To retrieve rows from other tables when performing joins. MySQL can
>   use indexes on columns more efficiently if they are declared as the
>   same type and size. In this context, VARCHAR and CHAR are considered
>   the same if they are declared as the same size. For example,
>   VARCHAR(10) and CHAR(10) are the same size, but VARCHAR(10) and
>   CHAR(15) are not.
>
> For comparisons between nonbinary string columns, both columns should
>   use the same character set. For example, comparing a utf8 column with
>   a latin1 column precludes use of an index.
>
> Comparison of dissimilar columns (comparing a string column to a
>   temporal or numeric column, for example) may prevent use of indexes if
>   values cannot be compared directly without conversion. For a given
>   value such as 1 in the numeric column, it might compare equal to any
>   number of values in the string column such as '1', ' 1', '00001', or
>   '01.e1'. This rules out use of any indexes for the string column.
>
> To find the MIN() or MAX() value for a specific indexed column
>   key_col. This is optimized by a preprocessor that checks whether you
>   are using WHERE key_part_N = constant on all key parts that occur
>   before key_col in the index. In this case, MySQL does a single key
>   lookup for each MIN() or MAX() expression and replaces it with a
>   constant. If all expressions are replaced with constants, the query
>   returns at once. For example:
>
> To sort or group a table if the sorting or grouping is done on a
>   leftmost prefix of a usable index (for example, ORDER BY key_part1,
>   key_part2). If all key parts are followed by DESC, the key is read in
>   reverse order. See Section 9.2.1.15, “ORDER BY Optimization”, and
>   Section 9.2.1.16, “GROUP BY Optimization”.
>
> In some cases, a query can be optimized to retrieve values without
>   consulting the data rows. (An index that provides all the necessary
>   results for a query is called a covering index.) If a query uses from
>   a table only columns that are included in some index, the selected
>   values can be retrieved from the index tree for greater speed:

Comment: Thank @Stack  .. i have added some part of doc by mysql .. hope useful

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is never a correct answer about indexing , the correct answer will be different each time depending on the size of your data, the types of the columns and ETC.

When deciding which indexes is best for a table you should consider the following:

- What are the most common functions I am doing on this table?
- How many times a day this functions occuring?
- What are the slowest queries that affect my performance the most?

After that, when you have the queries you actually need to improve (An update that happens a lot, a select/join and ETC) you can decide which is the correct indexes with the explain plan from each query.

You should know that when indexing like your example `mytable(col1, col2, col3)` , it will be able to use even part of the index as long as the column needed is mentioned first in the index

So, every use of `Col1` will indeed be able to use this index. `Col2` will be used only in case it is combined with `Col1` as well and so on for `Col3` (has to be combined with both `col1` and `col2` in order to be used).

You can find a lot of information about indexing [on MySQL documantation .](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Answer (score 1):

> Would following queries benefit from this index  mytable(col1, col2, col3)

```
. . . WHERE col1 = ? AND col3 = ?
```

col1 benefits from the index and for col3 residual predicate may be used

```
. . . WHERE col2 = ?
```

SQL may choose to scan the index you have if it is cost effective,so in summary this wont be used

```
. . . WHERE col1 IN (?, ?)
```

Index will be used

```
. . . WHERE col3 = ? AND col1 NOT IN (?, ?)
```

col1 benefits from the index and for col3 residual predicate will be used

```
. . . WHERE col1 = ? OR col2 = ?
```

Index will be used

```
. . . WHERE col2 = ? AND col1 = ?
```

Index will be used

```
. . . WHERE col1 = ? AND col2 > ?
```

Index will be used

```
. . . WHERE col1 = ? AND col3 > ?
```

Index will be used

A residual predicate is a probe which SQL applies to rows left over after applying first index.